# A connection issue with open file dialog in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, messagebox, openfiledialog

I'm having a issue when trying to open a `.mdf` file with a open file dialog. When I go to open it, it gives me a message box saying it cannot be opened and that its currently in use. How would you close the current connection and have it open that one? Or if you've seen this issue before what are some things I could try to get the connection working?

Comment: You'd have to shut down the instance of SQL Server that's using it. Praytell, what are you actually trying to do? This sounds dangerous.

Comment: You cant open a database thru a FileDialog in any meaningful way so what is the point?